# MultiDataTrigger.Conditions Check binding type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to check that the `ListBox` element has a specific type to assign a visual style to, but the constant check fails. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Problem with this line:

```
Condition Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Type econemodels:DishDTOAdvance}"
```

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">    
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding}"
                                           Value="{x:Type econemodels:DishDTOAdvance}" />
                    
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                                    Value="{StaticResource DishNoImage}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding fails, because it binds an *instance* of type `DishDTOAdvance` and compares it with an **instance of [`Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-6.0)** that describes the `DishDTOAdvance` type. Obviously they are different types and the condition is never true. In XAML [`x:Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xtype-markup-extension) is like `typeof()` or [`GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=net-6.0) in code.

> The `x:Type` markup extension has a similar function to the `typeof()` operator in C# or the GetType operator in Microsoft Visual Basic. The `x:Type` markup extension supplies a from-string conversion behavior for properties that take the type Type.

That is exactly the case for a custom [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.DataTemplateSelector);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0), no need for bindings.

> Provides a way to choose a `DataTemplate` based on the data object and the data-bound element.

With a data template selector you can provide arbitrary logic to choose a data template for an item. In your case a `switch` statement for the type is enough to choose a template that can be found through [`FindResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResource);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) in the resources up the visual tree. Of course you could also assign data templates trough properties if you do not want to search in all resources.

```
public class TypeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
   public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
   {
      var contentPresenter = (ContentPresenter)container;

      switch (item)
      {
         case DishDTOAdvance _:
            return (DataTemplate)contentPresenter.FindResource("DishNoImage");
         // ...other type cases.
         default:
            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
      }
   }
}
```

Create and add an instance of the data template selector to your `ListBox`. Remove the `ItemTemplate` completely, it it now automatically assigned by the selector.

```
<ListBox ...>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
      <local:TypeTemplateSelector/>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
   <!-- ...other markup. -->
</ListBox>
```

The `ContentControl` is redundant. However in case you need it within an item template, it works just the same. `ContentControl` exposes an [`ContentTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property for the same purpose.

---

Bonus round: Is the trigger impossible? No. You can create a converter that returns the type.

```
public class TypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return value?.GetType();
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

Create an instance of the converter in a resource dictionary in scope.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:TypeConverter x:Key="TypeConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Use the converter in the condition binding. Now types are compared.

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TypeConverter}}"
           Value="{x:Type econemodels:DishDTOAdvance}"/>
```